# How to implement a SaveFileDialog in my code, where I am using a FileSteam object

Tags: vb.net, filestream, streamwriter, savefiledialog

so here is my code with the method, but I cannot seem to figure out how to implement a Save File Dialog within... Any information or guidance will be highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub btSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btSave.Click
        If (cbPeriod.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing) Then
            Try
                Using connect As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                    Dim command As New SqlCommand()
                    command.CommandText = selectQuery
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", cbPeriod.SelectedItem.ToString)
                    command.Connection = connect
                    Dim fileName As String
                    fileName = "Data.txt"
                    Dim seqNo As Integer = 0
                    Dim currDocNo As String = ""
                    Dim prevDocNo As String = ""
                    Using FileObject As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                        Using StreamWriterObj As New StreamWriter(FileObject)
                            connect.Open()
                            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                                Dim FieldCount As Integer = reader.FieldCount - 1
                                For i = 0 To FieldCount
                                    StreamWriterObj.Write(reader.GetName(i).ToString)
                                    StreamWriterObj.Write(" @ ")
                                Next
                                StreamWriterObj.WriteLine()
                                Do While reader.Read()
                                    currDocNo = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("ДокументNo")).ToString
                                    StreamWriterObj.Write(reader.Item(0))
                                    For i = 1 To FieldCount
                                        currDocNo = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("ДокументNo")).ToString
                                        If (reader.GetName(i).Equals("ПореденНомер", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
                                            If (currDocNo = prevDocNo) Then
                                                seqNo += 1
                                                StreamWriterObj.Write(seqNo)
                                            Else
                                                seqNo = 1
                                                StreamWriterObj.Write(" @ ")
                                                StreamWriterObj.Write(seqNo)
                                            End If
                                        Else
                                            StreamWriterObj.Write(" @ ")
                                            StreamWriterObj.Write(reader.Item(i))
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                    prevDocNo = currDocNo
                                    StreamWriterObj.WriteLine()
                                Loop
                                reader.Close()
                            End Using
                            connect.Close()
                            MessageBox.Show("Export was successful.")
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a value!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

If you need further information let me know. As you can see I have the File object and everything so i guess i will just need to add some savefiledialog but how to get the data that the streamwriter has into the savefiledialog?

Comment: Nothing goes into a FileDialog.  It just allows the user to specify the desired path and filename.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Don't explicitly call `Close()` on your disposable objects you have wrapped in `Using` blocks. The Dispose method is called and it closes it for you @ `End Using`.

Comment: You can also get rid of the FileStream and use the StreamWriter to create the file as well using [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SaveFileDialog to get a filename like this

```
Dim fileName As String
' fileName = "Data.txt"
Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
    sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If sfd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fileName = sfd.FileName
    Else
        Throw New Exception("User canceled out of save dialog")
    End If
End Using
```

Don't explicitly call `Close()` on your disposable objects you have wrapped in `Using` blocks. The Dispose method is called and it closes it for you @ `End Using`

Lastly, you can remove the FileStream and use the StreamWriter to create the file as well using [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog.filter(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
' Using FileObject As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
' Using StreamWriterObj As New StreamWriter(FileObject)
Using StreamWriterObj As New StreamWriter(path:=fileName, append:=False)
```

Comment: Wow, i thought it was going to be more complicated than this. Thank you for the help :)